# Is there an equivalent to Django template filters in mako?

Tags: python, mako

I know there is some filtering capability in Mako (even allowed with multiple filters), but all I found in the docs are very basic ones concerning basic text escaping etc..

Is there something similiar (I prefer Mako over django with the a ability to use raw python in the template

Comment: Suggestion: Don't use Mako. It's horrible. And putting raw python code in a template file is a **damn bad idea**. Templates are not supposed to contain actual code.

Comment: @ThiefMaster thanks for the comment, but still I like Mako (better in many ways than django template language - maybe jinja2 is also as good) and I don't like Django telling me what way to code.  maybe putting some raw python to solve a specific problem is a good solution for me? maybe I want to solve something quick and dirty and optimize for beauty or performance later?

Comment: The thing is: If you "plan to improve it later" chances are good this will never happen. (It works after all. Why change something that already works?)